# Programmatical ViewState

Tags: asp.net

View state can store the page value at the time of post back (Sending and Receiving information from Server) of your page. 
 View State stored the value of page controls as a string which is hashed and encoded in some hashing and encoding technology. We can see it in the page.

My Question : We can also declare the programmatically View state in the code behind , during the round trip ,where is it maintain in the page life cycle, can we see in the page?

Comment: You mean to not saved it on page, but on server ?

Comment: my question : how to maintain that view state, which is defined in the code behind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All ViewState is stored in a hidden field on the page. Just view source and you will see a hidden field called ViewState. It's typically Base64 encoded.
If you want to see it in clear text you can Base64 decode the content of the hidden field